# Low PPPoE speed in Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, ppp

We have 2 PC with Ubuntu 12.04 and connect with 1000M/bit cable. We then start `iperf` on both PCs and get 900m/bit speed using the `iftop` tool.

However, when we setup [PPPoE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-point_protocol_over_Ethernet) server on the 1st PC, and [PPPoE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-point_protocol_over_Ethernet) client on the 2nd PC, and direct `iperf` over [PPPoE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-point_protocol_over_Ethernet), we get only 430M/bit.

#### questions

- Is it normal that PPPoE on Linux so slow?
- Is there any way to get speeds similar to the direct connect option?

Comment: How does PPPoA compare?  [This](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.network/233089) maybe related.

Comment: Does your gig link support oversized (Jumbo) frames ?

Comment: Interesting that you can only drive 900Mbit using a dedicated testing tool. Anyway, I wonder if you're using TCP offload. Linux is able to offload some TCP/IP processing... TCP/IP/PPPoE might not support this as well, depending on implementation details... you could compare with various offloads enabled (`ethtool`), see whether your system can still drive 900Mbit even without offloads, it might be a useful data point. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/segmentation-offloads.txt

Answer (score 1):

PPPoE has some overhead: 8 bytes **per packet**. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-point_protocol_over_Ethernet#Protocol_overhead). So it needs more packets to send the same amount of data, thus effectively reducing bandwith.

Obviously, 8 bytes per packet should not **half** the bandwidth if the packets are big enough (1000-1500 bytes).

But if `iperf` uses sufficently small packets (64 bytes perhaps?) the overhead should be enough to give the results you're experiencing.

You could also be experiencing [fragmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_fragmentation), i.e. `iperf` tries to send 1500 bytes packets while PPPoE should have a `1492 MTU`. Try the `iperf` with `-M` option:

```
-M, --mss n
          set TCP maximum segment size (MTU - 40 bytes)
```

To be safe pass it a value of 1400:

```
iperf -c X.X.X.X -M 1400
```

Also, try running it for some time, like 60 or 120 seconds

```
iperf -c X.X.X.X -M 1400 -s 60 # or 120
```